# PHP echo'ing a variable with a div

Tags: php, html, echo

Okay guys so I'm trying to make a login system with a verification email getting sent to your email but when I want to give the user a message, whether their account has been made or not and style it with a div tag it just does this [to my webpage](https://gyazo.com/4b94ac5b074090c3f62cecb951ccdf04). 
And when I try to remove the div tag [it gives me nothing](https://gyazo.com/2968bc3b91c655ae202cc39b01a91e28). 
 What am I doing wrong?
BTW. I'm not done yet with everything.

```
<?php

    mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("registrations") or die(mysqli_error());


    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $name = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
        $email = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
    }

    if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        $msg = 'You have entered a invalid email.';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Your account has been made, please click the link in the email getting sent to you for verifying your account.';
        $hash = md5( rand(0 , 1000) );
        $password = rand(1000,5000);
    }

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, hash) VALUES(
    '". mysqli_escape_string($name) ."', 
    '". mysqli_escape_string(md5($password)) ."', 
    '". mysqli_escape_string($email) ."', 
    '". mysqli_escape_string($hash) ."') ") or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

#### Sign Up

```
    <p>Please enter your email and name to sign up.</p>

    <?php

        if (isset($msg)){
            echo '<div class="statusmsg">' . $msg . '</div>';
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: What's the actual HTML being sent to the browser?  Maybe PHP isn't even executing?

Comment: The whole code  http://pastebin.com/Xq7WZ4E3

Comment: Please do use `mysqli_escape_string()` to sterilize your mysql input. To stop mysql injection use prepared statements. You are already using `mysqli` so please use prepared statements. Check them out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp), they are a must if you are creating a login system.

Comment: @MagnusJensen: If that is indeed the HTML code being sent to the browser then PHP isn't running at all on your page.  You should never see server-side code in the browser.

Comment: No, and I wonder why I'm seeing it because everything else isn't showing but that is and I don't know why?

Comment: @MagnusJensen: "No"?  Then what *is* the HTML code being sent to the browser?  You need to look at the client-side page source, nobody here can see what's happening in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use `empty` instead of `isset`

so the code is

```
if(!empty($msg)){
    //have your div here
}
```

my 2 cents: dont write html and php together...separate them...avoid short tags....

```
<?php 
  if(!empty($msg)){ 
?>
    <div class="statusmsg"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip keeping those 2 seperate, when I took your advice it wouldn't show the text from before so that is fixed, but it wont show any message after clicking the button. And it created a little grey field.